# Select, create blank lines between the transition of different values

Tags: mysql

How can I, during a select ordered by some field, add empty/blank lines between the transition of different values?
In this case when the field `ACCESS_DATE`, some value gets diferent from the previous value.

**My Select Query:**

`` SELECT * FROM `CONTROL_TAB` ORDER BY `ACCESS_DATE` DESC ``

**Intended Result:**

[image]

Comment: sql does not do pretty print(and it's not it's job) - do this in your front end..

Comment: Agreed. Handle issues of data display in application code

Comment: Ok, Thanks guys. I thought somehow it's possible. There's a way to mark the last item of the date before a transition? With a "1" or something?

Comment: Yep. All possible. Don't.